# System of differential equation correct

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've solved the following system of differential equation but I'm not sure if it's correct, can someone check it?

\begin{cases} z'+z+4y=e^x \\ 2z+3y+y'=0 \end{cases}

I've got the following answer:

\begin{cases} y=Ae_{}^{-5x}+Be^x-\frac{xe^x}{3} \\ z=Ae_{}^{-5x}-2Be^x-\frac{xe^x}{6}+\frac{e^x}{6} \end{cases}

Comment: If it's simply to check your answer, [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%7Bz%27%2Bz%2B4y%3De%5Ex,2z%2B3y%2By%27%3D0%7D) is your friend.

Comment: I tried but it gives me something really weird... Or am I just wrong?

Comment: You'll have to simplify a bit, expand the brackets.

Comment: I did, but the answer it gives me still looks weird in my eyes

Answer (score 1):

Without showing your work, I can't tell where it went wrong but following up on the comments, you can use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%7Bz%27%2Bz%2B4y%3De%5Ex,2z%2B3y%2By%27%3D0%7D) to check and after expanding and simplifying a bit ([for $y$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20y(x)%20%3D%201%2F3%20c_1%20e%5E(-5%20x)%20(e%5E(6%20x)%20%2B%202)%20-%201%2F3%20c_2%20e%5E(-5%20x)%20(e%5E(6%20x)%20-%201)%20%2B%201%2F18%20e%5Ex%20(1%20-%206%20x)) and [for $z$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand%20z(x)%20%3D%20-2%2F3%20c_1%20e%5E(-5%20x)%20(e%5E(6%20x)%20-%201)%20%2B%201%2F3%20c_2%20e%5E(-5%20x)%20(2%20e%5E(6%20x)%20%2B%201)%20%2B%201%2F18%20e%5Ex%20(12%20x%20%2B%201))) you can see that you have the homogeneous part correct but there are a few mistakes in the other terms:

> $$\begin{cases} y=Ae_{}^{-5x}+Be^x-\frac{xe^x}{3} \\ z=Ae_{}^{-5x}-2Be^x-\frac{xe^x}{6}+\frac{e^x}{6} \end{cases}$$

should be

$$\begin{cases} y=Ae_{}^{-5x}+Be^x-\frac{xe^x}{3}\color{blue}{+\frac{e^x}{18}} \\ z=Ae_{}^{-5x}-2Be^x\color{red}{+\frac{2xe^x}{3}}+\frac{e^x}{\color{red}{18}} \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let us try calculating this without resorting to external tools:

We convert your above ODE into a first order system:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{z} \\
    \dot{y} \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
    -1 & -4 \\
    -2 & -3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    z \\
    y \\
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
    e^t \\
    0 \\
\end{bmatrix}..$$

It is generally good practice to first solve the homogenous system

$$\dot{x}=Ax$$

so that we can create a fundamental system of solutions.

Calculating the eigenvalues and eigenvectors leads us to
the homogenous solution $x_c$:
$$x_c=c_1
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    -0.5 \\
\end{pmatrix}
e^{t}+c_2
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
e^{-5t},$$
with $c_1,c_2\in\mathbb{R}.$

Because initial values often start at $t=0$, we convert the above into a standard fundamental matrix $\Phi_0(t)$ for $t=0$. This can be done by calculating the matrix exponential:

$\Phi_0(t)=e^{At}.$

Because the eigenvalues are real and their algebraic multiplicity coincides with the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvectors, we can factorize $A$ into:
$$A=SDS^{-1}.$$

Now calculation of the matrix exponential is greatly simplified:

$e^{At}=e^{SDS^{-1}}=Se^{D}S^{-1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
    1 && 1 \\
    -0.5 && 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    e^t&&0 \\
    0&&e^{-5t} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
    1&&-1 \\
    0.5&&1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\frac{2}{3}.$

This simplifies to:

$$e^{At}=
\begin{pmatrix}
    e^t+\frac{e^{-5t}}{2} && -e^t+e^{-5t} \\
    -\frac{e^t}{2}+\frac{e^{-5t}}{2} && \frac{e^t}{2}+e^{-5t} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\frac{2}{3}.$$

You can always check if above is correct by plugging it into the homogenous ODE $\dot{x}=Ax$ and comparing with the manually computed derivative $\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_0(t).$

Now that we have the complementary solution $x_c=e^{At}$ we calculate a particular solution $x_p$ of the nonhomogenous equation.

Using variation of parameters, we have to calculate
$\Phi_0(t)\int\Phi_0(t)^{-1}\cdot b(t) dt.$

You can calculate the inverse for a nonconstant matrix just as you would do with constant entries. Don't forget our $\frac{2}{3}$ factor when calculating $\Phi_0(t)^{-1}$!

This leads to a particular solution
$x_p=\frac{12}{18}
\begin{pmatrix}
te^t+\frac{e^t}{12} \\
-\frac{te^t}{2}+\frac{e^t}{12}
\end{pmatrix}
$.

Again, you can easily check this manually.

All solutions are then the combination of the particular and complementary solution:

$x=x_c+x_p$.